# Mac shortcuts in Slack on a non-UK keyboard like Danish are not working

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, slack

I have a very annoying problem with many Mac programs, including Slack. Some shortcuts are using special characters like [ and ]. Slack uses cmd-[ and cmd-] to navigate back and forth in history.

However, on a Danish keyboard this character is normally accessed through alt-8.

Now the trouble is that I cannot make this short cut work no matter what I press. I tried:

- alt-8
- alt-cmd-8
- cmd-8

and other crazy combinations.

What to do? Slack is really difficult to use without this ability.

Comment: Questions like these are not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for questions about **programming** computers, not just using them.

Answer (score 1):

In slack, the shortcuts are all hard-coded in. If the shortcut is looking for **keyboard event properties** *keyCode* or *charCode* number `91 = '['` and `93 = ']'` then the shortcut will never work since the keyboard is going to have different values for different keys.

https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html